# Texto CheckBox "Sim" e não "True"

Tags: vba, checkbox

Boa tarde,

estou produzindo um formulário e preciso saber como faço para que quando o CheckBox estiver selecionado ele entregue o texto "Sim" e não "Verdadeiro" (meu excel esta em português) . Acredito que esta seja uma solução simples porém não consigo saber como finaliza-la.

Obrigado.

Comment: Faça uma condição: SE("Verdadeiro";"Sim";"Não");

Comment: Valeu a resposta rápida Ivan!

O problema é que preciso colocar isso no código, então ele vai sobrescrever qualquer coisa que eu colocar na planilha...

Comment: Que código? coloca o seu código aí para eu poder te ajudar.